# C# DataSet Question - What does the value in quotes mean?

Tags: dataset, c#-2.0

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet("PinkElephant");
```

Can anyone give me insight into what PinkElephant means in this context. I understand that I'm declaring a new DataSet Object, but what is PinkElephant? Is it simply the name of the DataSet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name given to the DataSet for use in creating an XML document's root tag. Without specifying it yourself, it'll create something up itself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7se64052.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.dataset.aspx), it's the name

More specifically, that [constructors doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7se64052.aspx)